2 (almost) identical Supermicro systems different performance
2 almost identical Supermicro systems
X10DRU-i+
and identical CPUs
2x 2697A per system
. Whatsmore the OS is identical as they are imaged with the same OS image of Windows 2016 server standard.
The only difference between the two is
System 1 is 6018U-TR4+ and system 2 is 6018U-TR4T+. But the motherboards are identical.
The CPU performance as measured by Performance test software between these are very different though.

the TR4+ is on left and the TR4T+ is on right. It seems to me the 2nd system has performance equivalent of single cpu system and not dual yet all cores are used when I look while it's running the test.
here is geekbench:

Bios is set to same settings on CPU performance

Only obvious difference i see is in bios version but notably CPLD on one but no CPLD on another:

Also I tried to upgrade the BIOS on the second system but I get this on the 2nd system:

I am using the correct BIOS linked to my board/chasis config
https://www.supermicro.com/en/support/resources/downloadcenter/firmware/MBD-X10DRU-i+/BIOS
Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this appreciated.

Can't even upgrade the firmware? Open a support ticket with the vendor. Also this is not "almost identical".

it is. check the specs. only difference is the ethernet card

Not with the difference in firmware.

bios should not have this kind of impact. and i have that version bios on other configs and it's perfectly fine

Seriously, this isn't a forum for old junk hardware.

I see. I don't see that in the forum description. Thought it's a forum for solving technical problems not make elitist condescending comments. Could it be more likely you are mistaken Greg.

@mart The CPU's are from 2016. They have been End of service for a couple of years. You have no warranty. We expect you to adhere to reasonable practices.

that's irrelevant. i did not ask you to replace them for me did i?
all of them act the same way with the bios difference so it's not a defect. in the cpu quite obviously if you don't know the answer i'd suggest don't comment. i'm quite aware the cpus are old but it's an irrelevant point to make here. you are not giving any information that is not already known.
